# How to recreate mac scrollbar fade in and out when scrolling starts in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, scrollbar

I am starting with this:

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar {

}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-button {

}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {


}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {

}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  width: 6px;
  background-color: red;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {

}

*::-webkit-resizer {

}
```

How do I go about recreating the functionality of animating/fading-in the scrollbar *only when you start scrolling*, and then when you hover over the scrollbar, *it gets wider*. Right now if I try to style it using these methods, it is permanently present. Do I need custom JavaScript to do this or is there another way?

I just want to change the background image of all the scrollbars, but have it still work like all the existing mac scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a pure CSS solution for you, I tend to do this in JS with the use of [a custom scrollbar library](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) (*not affiliated with me*).

Once the library is added you can simply use the following jQuery to initialise it:

```
$('.container').mCustomScrollbar({
    theme: "dark-3", // some theme examples: http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollbar_themes_demo.html
    autoExpandScrollbar: true, //options list can be found here http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#configuration-section
    autoHideScrollbar: true
});
```

Here's a working example below:

```js
$('.container').mCustomScrollbar({
  theme: "dark-3",
  autoExpandScrollbar: true,
  autoHideScrollbar: true
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container p {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <p>This is a test 1</p>
  <p>This is a test 2</p>
  <p>This is a test 3</p>
  <p>This is a test 4</p>
  <p>This is a test 5</p>
  <p>This is a test 6</p>
  <p>This is a test 7</p>
  <p>This is a test 8</p>
  <p>This is a test 9</p>
  <p>This is a test 10</p>
  <p>This is a test 11</p>
  <p>This is a test 12</p>
  <p>This is a test 13</p>
  <p>This is a test 14</p>
  <p>This is a test 15</p>
  <p>This is a test 16</p>
  <p>This is a test 17</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If it's not possible to do in CSS, then knowing how to do it in vanilla JS (as opposed to jQuery or a library) would be helpful.

Comment: @LancePollard - I definitely agree with you - this is still a valid solution if no one can provide you with a vanilla js solution though, but good luck! :)